# Very slow Postgres UPDATE on large table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a Postgres 9.1.3 table with 2.06 million rows after **WHERE Y=1** as per below (it only has a few ten thousand more rows total without any **WHERE**). I am trying to add data to an empty field with a query like this:

```
WITH B AS (
    SELECT Z,
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY L, N, M, P) AS X
    FROM   A
    WHERE  Y=1
)

UPDATE A
SET A.X = B.X
FROM B
WHERE A.Y=1
  AND B.Z = A.Z;
```

This query runs for hours and appears to progress very slowly. In fact, the second time I tried this, I had a power outage after the query ran for ~3 hours. After restoring power, I analyzed the table and got this:

```
INFO:  analyzing "consistent.master"
INFO:  "master": scanned 30000 of 69354 pages, containing 903542 live rows and 153552 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 2294502 estimated total rows
Total query runtime: 60089 ms.
```

Is it correct to interpret that the query had barely progressed in those hours?

I have done a **VACUUM FULL** and **ANALYZE** before running the long query.

The query within the **WITH** only takes 40 seconds.

All fields referenced above except A.X, and by extension B.X, are indexed: L, M, N, P, Y, Z.

This is being run on a laptop with 8 GB RAM, a Core i7 Q720 1.6 GHz quad core processor, and Windows 7 x64. I am running Postgres 32 bit for compatibility with PostGIS 1.5.3. 64 bit PostGIS for Windows isn't available yet. (32 bit Postgres means it can't use more than 2 GB RAM in Windows, but I doubt that's an issue here.)

Here's the result of EXPLAIN:

```
Update on A  (cost=727684.76..945437.01 rows=2032987 width=330)
  CTE B
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=491007.50..542482.47 rows=2058999 width=43)
          ->  Sort  (cost=491007.50..496155.00 rows=2058999 width=43)
                Sort Key: A.L, A.N, A.M, A.P
                ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..85066.80 rows=2058999 width=43)
                      Filter: (Y = 1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=185202.29..402954.54 rows=2032987 width=330)
        Hash Cond: ((B.Z)::text = (A.Z)::text)
        ->  CTE Scan on B  (cost=0.00..41179.98 rows=2058999 width=88)
        ->  Hash  (cost=85066.80..85066.80 rows=2058999 width=266)
              ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..85066.80 rows=2058999 width=266)
                    Filter: (Y = 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand the figures. The table contains 2 million rows. How many rows does the condition `WHERE Y=1` select from that?

Comment: Post `EXPLAIN` or (if it completes) `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output please.

Comment: If the `Y=1` part is very selective (as in my randomly generated data) then the update is done within milliseconds. So please provide either a [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) example of the data.

Comment: Just did third attempt and let it run all night. It's run for 17.6 hours so far and has not completed. All of you have good questions. I'll have to provide answers later today.

Comment: Just added the EXPLAIN results. Will try to get back to this tonight, probably in a 7+ hours, to get the rest of the requested info.

Comment: All: Very sorry, have been away from the computer almost all day. I'll try my best to get back to this sometime tomorrow.

Comment: @A.H.: Y=1 is rather unselective. It reduces the table to 2.06 million rows after removing a few tens of thousands?

Comment: This seem to be the follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900122/why-did-postgres-update-take-39-hours?noredirect=1

Comment: Yes, it is. I had more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be multiple solutions.

- The update could be blocked on a lock. Consult pg_locks view.
- Maybe there are triggers on A? They could be the reason for slowdown.
- Try "explain update... " - is the plan significantly different than the plan of plain select? Maybe You could do it in 2 steps - export "B" to a table, and update from that table.
- Try dropping the indexes before the update.
- Create a new table, drop the old one, rename the new table to old table's name.

Comment: My bet is on a (b)locking problem. I tried the update on my pretty-outdated desktop and updating 2 million rows with the original statement took ~4 minutes.

Comment: I am the only user of this DB. Wouldn't that preclude (b)locking? No triggers. The EXPLAIN results are in my edited post. I think it separates the UDPATE and SELECT? Good idea about the 2nd table; I'll see if I can try that later today.

Comment: Just to make sure, you wrote "dropping the indexes before the update". Wouldn't that make things worse? The updated field (**A.X**) is not indexed, and I have **WHERE** clauses involving **A.Y** and **A.Z**.

Comment: @ArenCambre: As you can see i your query plan _no_ index is used. This is so, because A.Y is extremely unselective and even A.Z (which seems to be some unique id) won't help because you update nearly the complete table anyway. But I also doubt, that dropping the indexes will help you considerably.

Comment: Oh, wow, I see what you mean. I just did an **EXPLAIN** on a simple query on another table with an index, and I see where the index is explicitly mentioned in the results. I am not clear why the indexing is not working. Regardless, I've marked @maniek's answer as the correct one since his last bullet appears to be the best answer.

Comment: Dropping index, updating the whole table and recreating the index is considerably faster than just updating the whole table. The indexes are not used in the update, which is a good thing when You are scanning the whole table anyway. Sequential disk access is orders of magnitude faster than random access.

Comment: I had a similar issue and dropping the index and creating it again afterward changed the timing from about 40 minutes to just a few seconds.

Comment: I think Postgresql has a problem with updating a high proportion of rows in a large table. I hit the same wall twice now with this pattern `WITH ... AS ([complex query, runs by itself in minutes]) [simple update statement]` (never finishes after hours). You shouldn't need to drop and re-create tables like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the query like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.X = B.X
FROM B
WHERE A.Y=1
      AND B.Z = A.Z
      AND A.X IS DISTINCT FROM B.X;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH B AS (
  
  -- list all the columns in your table in order including the one to be "updated"
  SELECT L, N, M, P,
         rank() OVER (ORDER BY L, N, M, P) AS X,
         Y, Z
  FROM   A
  WHERE  Y=1

), D AS (

   DELETE FROM A WHERE Y=1

)
INSERT INTO A
SELECT * FROM B
```

I have used this a couple of times now to fix a never-ending update.  The above pattern was completing for me on millions of rows in minutes.

One of those times I had primary key conflicts. That was solved by `DROP`ing the primary key before running the above statement and re-`CREATE`ing it afterwards. I am surprised that's necessary since in my CTE, the conflicting values are deleted before the insert happens, but oh well.